# Wildcard in variable name

Tags: octopus-deploy

I have a use case where I want to do array indexing for the name of some variables. In this case, I want all of these to direct to the same value:

```
ReverseProxy:Routes:0:Match:Hosts:0 = MyDomain.com
ReverseProxy:Routes:1:Match:Hosts:0 = MyDomain.com
ReverseProxy:Routes:2:Match:Hosts:0 = MyDomain.com
ReverseProxy:Routes:3:Match:Hosts:0 = MyDomain.com
```

Is it possible have a wildcard in the variable name e.g. `ReverseProxy:Routes:*:Match:Hosts:0` so that I could just define this once? This is a reverse proxy service that will continue to have new services added and I'd need to add a line for this every time.

I couldn't find any documentation describing whether a wildcard in the variable name is allowed.